# How to use python to look how much light is outside

Tags: python-3.x, macos, github

I made a Program on GitHub called: https://github.com/bigboy32/MacOSmojave

But the only issue is it is doing it based on the time, not based on the sunlight

**So what is the Error/Question**

let's say it is 7 pm and it is light outside and the pc is showing 'An Evening' background!

So that's my Question

Thanks to all the answers!

Comment: Have you considered using the sunrise and sunset variables for your area?

Comment: How to do so? So what do i need to do for it?

Comment: You could pull the information from the national weather service.

Comment: You could also look at the status of your Mac's low light mode.

Comment: Thanks but how can I pull it

Comment: By the way I am using Linux

Comment: I assumed that you were using MacOS, because you used that tag on your question.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to make my ubuntu look like a mac

Comment: Does your hardware (laptop) have a built-in ambient light sensor?  If so, do some research on how to query that sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any weather measurement service with opens API to retrieve the information you want, like [this one](https://openweathermap.org/api/uvi)

This API returns the UVI values, you can interprete this and create the logic, since the UVI will be lower when the sun is going down.

Comment: I sadly never worked with UVI so i don't know how to use it

Comment: It's simple, the UV is higher when the sun is up and lower when the sun has gone. Everyone never did until they do. This is a proper solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Get a [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w) for $12 and attach a [Light Dependent Resistor](https://www.kitronik.co.uk/blog/how-an-ldr-light-dependent-resistor-works/) to it. Read the light once a minute and send the reading to your computer via WiFi.

Comment: I have a Raspberry pi but is there an API?

Comment: An API for what?